# Find two smallest numbers using java?

Tags: java

I need help to compute the two smallest numbers in java?... plzz help.. Usage for arraylist and arrays are not allowed.. The user shall be asked for a terminating value first and will continue to provide inputs and once the user enters the same terminating value the program should output the two smallest numbers from the inputs excluding the terminating value..

Additional Details Could show me how to do it... The sentinel value is the value if entered again by the user shall stop the program and output the two smallest numbers.

```
package hw4;


public class s1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int input;
        int min;
        int min2;



        System.out.print("Enter a value to act as sentinel:");
        int sentinel = IO.readInt();

        System.out.println("Enter numbers");
        input = IO.readInt();

        do {

            min = input;
            min2 = input;

            if (input < min) {

                min = input;

            }



            input = IO.readInt();

        } while (input != sentinel);

        // Return the results
        System.out.println("The smallest Number is: " + min);
        System.out.println("The second smallest Number is: " + min2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework or a test, you shouldn't get help on that ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is homework, based on the nature of the question. So ...

Hint: if `x` *was* the smallest and `y` *is now* the smallest, then `x` *is now* the second smallest.

Hint 2: make sure your program works when the smallest and second smallest values are equal.

Answer (score 3):

When you find a new min, save the previous minimum in your `min2` variable and then reassign `min` to the current input.

```
   if (input < min) {
        min2 = min
        min = input;

    }
```

Comment: But what if the input is smaller than min2 but bigger than min?

Answer (score 1):

This would work if you needed to find only the smallest number, but you need to find the two smallest numbers, so the `if` should go like that:

```
if(input < min) {
    min2 = min;
    min = input;
}
else if (input < min2) {
    min2 = input;
}
```

And I know min & min2 need a value at start, so instead of changing their value to input every time, just do that at the fist time. So also get this part out of the `do`:

```
min = input;
min2 = input;
```

Comment: @Karan Singh - you won't learn much by copying answers from the internet.  And you'll regret it ... or at least your future co-workers will.