# How can I return the 2 smallest elements in an array?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm given a `List<Integer>` and I'm trying to return the 2 smallest integers in the List in a new array.

To do this, I have created a helper that finds the smallest number in the array and then used that in my main function, where I hope to use a while loop that runs until 2, since I need the 2 smallest numbers, and remove the first (smallest) number in order to find the next smallest number and then add them to the new array I made.

Here is my code:

```
public static int countSorthelper(List<Integer> arr) {
    int temp = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(n <= 2){
   for (int x = 0; x < arr.size(); x++){
       for (int y = x+1; y < arr.size() && y <= x+y; y++){
           if(arr.get(y) > arr.get(x)){
               temp = arr.get(x);
               n++;
           }
       }
   }
   }
   return temp;

}
public static List<Integer> countSort(List<Integer> arr){
    int n = 0;
    List<Integer> j = new ArrayList<>();
    while (n <= 2){
        countSorthelper(arr);
        arr.remove(countSorthelper(arr));
        j.add(countSorthelper(arr));
        n++;
    }
    return j;
}
```

When I try to run this, the output terminates due to too much running time, what changes do I need to make in my code??

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518078/how-to-sort-listinteger, sort your input and get the two smalles values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find two smallest numbers using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048665/find-two-smallest-numbers-using-java)

Comment: Sort the array ascending and pick first two elements from it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to sort as you can do this in linear time.  The code should be self explanatory but basically you need to do comparisons against both `min1` and `min2`, exchanging their values as appropriate.  You can see this  in the output.  The values will either be `equal`, or `min1 will be the smallest` and `min2 the next smallest`.

If you want to return them you can return them in a record.

```
record Minimums(int smallest, int nextSmallest) {}

List<Integer> list = List.of(1,10,2,5,10,-2,22,3,-1);
Minimums mins = findSmallest(list);
System.out.println("\n"+mins);
```

- as `min1` changes, `min1` replaces `min2`
- but the next value in the list could be larger than `min1` but smaller than `min2` so `min2` needs to be independently tested.

```
   
public static Minimums findSmallest(List<Integer> list) {
    int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int val : list) {
        if (val < min1) {
            min2 = min1;
            min1 = val;

        } else if (val < min2) {
            min2 = val;
        }
        System.out.printf("val = %2d : min1 = %2d,  min2 = %2d\n", val,
                min1, min2);
    }
    return new Minimums(min1, min2);
}
```

prints

```
val =  1 : min1 =  1,  min2 = 2147483647
val = 10 : min1 =  1,  min2 = 10
val =  2 : min1 =  1,  min2 =  2
val =  5 : min1 =  1,  min2 =  2
val = 10 : min1 =  1,  min2 =  2
val = -2 : min1 = -2,  min2 =  1
val = 22 : min1 = -2,  min2 =  1
val =  3 : min1 = -2,  min2 =  1
val = -1 : min1 = -2,  min2 = -1

Minimums[smallest=-2, nextSmallest=-1]
```

Comment: I think this does what you want.